# Updating Image Upload in a MERN application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, image, multer

I'm trying to create CRUD operations for magazine products. Each product has a title, description, price and images. I have used multer (for the first time) to create a multi-image upload when the user **creates** a product from the admin area. This gets saved to MongoDB.

But now I'm trying to write the update/edit operation and for the other inputs, I fetch the product from the server and populate the `defaultValue` of the input with the data. The one thing I'm having an issue with is the image upload. I know you can't have a `defaultValue` for `type="file"` for security reasons so how do I get the image to overwrite **if** a new image is uploaded **or** don't delete the image if no new image is uploaded. To be clear, every time I edit the product (the title or the price), the image gets deleted as no image was uploaded.

Also, the other fields like title and price, update perfectly every time.

Here is my code:

component.jsx

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { title, description, imageUpload, price } = e.target;
    const arrayOfYourFiles = Array.from(imageUpload.files);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", title.value);
    formData.append("description", description.value);
    formData.append("price", price.value);
    arrayOfYourFiles.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append("imageUpload", file);
    });
    axios({
      method: "PUT",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/issue/" + id,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      alert("Issue updated");
      navigate("/admin");
    });
  };
...

<input name="imageUpload" multiple type="file" />
<label>Image upload</label>
```

app.js

```
app.put("/issue/:id", uploadMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, price } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body)
  const updatedIssue = {
    title,
    description,
    price,
    image: req.files.map((file) => file.path.replace("client/public", "")),
  };
  const result = await issuesCollection.updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { $set: updatedIssue }
  );
  res.status(200).json(result);
});

...

const uploadMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Use multer upload instance
  upload.array("imageUpload", 3)(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }

    // Retrieve uploaded files
    const files = req.files;
    const errors = [];

    // Validate file types and sizes
    files.forEach((file) => {
      const allowedTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];
      const maxSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

      if (!allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        errors.push(`Invalid file type: ${file.originalname}`);
      }

      if (file.size > maxSize) {
        errors.push(`File too large: ${file.originalname}`);
      }
    });

    // Handle validation errors
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      // Remove uploaded files
      files.forEach((file) => {
        fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
      });

      return res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }

    // Attach files to the request object
    req.files = files;

    // Proceed to the next middleware or route handler
    next();
  });
};
```

I've tried using a ternary operator to check if `imageUpload` has values, and if it does then use those new values to replace the image in the DB but if it's empty then use the state's `product.images` and even though the images are rendered on the page, when `handleSubmit` is called, it's magically empty...go figure

Comment: When are you calling your middleware? The sequence?

Comment: `app.put("/issue/:id", **uploadMiddleware**, async (req, res) ... `